# Как правильно переключаться между изображениями

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть рейтинг(изображение), как правильно переключаться между ними?
Каждый голос состоит из LinearLayout -> Imageview, TextView.
Как правильно реализовать: при нажатии на один из этих изображений менять цвет imageview на синий текст синий.
Хотел написать к каждому свой SetOnClickListener, но подумал вдруг есть более легкий способ.
Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Достаточно написать один `onClickListener` и присвоить его всем пятерым.

Comment: Можете ослеживать нажатия и смотреть на позию клика